# Definition of exponential terms

Tags: power-series, exponentiation

I'm having a hard time with this homework question. I can see that the inequalities hold and each of the three term converge to 1. But I'm not sure what what they mean by writing out the definition of each term. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Here is the question:

> Suppose $\quad\displaystyle \sum^\infty_{k=0}a_kx^k\quad$ is a power
>   series and $\quad \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} |a^k|^{1/k}=L>0
> > \quad$ converges.
>
> - Prove that $\quad k^{1/k}\leq (k+1)^{1/k}\leq (2k)^{1/k} \quad$ for    every $k\in \mathbb{N}$ by writing out the definition of each term
>     and using that log and exp are increasing functions.

Comment: Can you please type out the question? Question in images do not appear in search result, and are therefore hard to find duplicate, in future

Comment: They are just saying: "prove these inequalities."  The way you prove it is using the definition $a^b = e^{b\log a}$.

Comment: Since $y=\ln(x)$ and $y=e^x$ are increasing functions then it follows that if $0<a\le b\le c$ then $\ln(a)\le\ln(b)\le\ln(c)$ and that $e^a\le e^b\le e^c$.

Comment: $$1\le k <k+1\le k+k $$